# Is it OK to use "non" instead of "not" (and vice versa) in some contexts?

Tags: grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

> - Don't mix Boolean values with not Boolean ones.
> - Don't mix Boolean values with non-Boolean ones.

Which version is correct?

This question may look as if I hadn't did my own research, but it's not true. It's just too hard to find such things on Google. There are some questions-and-answers about the basic difference between "not" and "non", but they aren't really helpful here.

Comment: In this case, `non-Boolean` would be correct.

Comment: @svangordon Thanks, this is enough for me now, though some real answer with the explanation of how it works would be useful for other people here as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can say "This value is not Boolean."  In that example, the word "not" attaches to the verb "is", not to the adjective "Boolean".
To negate the adjective "Boolean", you can use the prefix "non-", with the meaning of anything other than Boolean.

These uses of "not" and "non-" are discussed in the first answer here:
[Stack Exchange "no, not, non"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/277210/no-not-and-non)